# Gmock for a nested object

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I need to make a mock for the function `foo`, which is called in `dosomething`, is it possible with gmock?

```
class Base
{
public:
    int foo()
    {

    }
};


class A {

   A()  {
     pointer = new Base();
    }

    double dosomething()
    {
        //more code
        pointer->foo();
    }

private:
    Base* pointer;
};
```

Comment: Which class do you want to test? If you are testing `A`, then you should inject dependency of `Base` and mock `foo` as usual. If you are testing some class that uses `A`, you should inject `A` and mock `dosomething()`. You shouldn't ever need nested mock structures in CoogleMock.

Comment: I want to test class A, specifically the dosomething function, I tried to make a mock for foo, but this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection). There are many ways to do that, I'll present the easiest one:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual int foo()
    {

    }
};

class BaseMock: public Base {
    MOCK_METHOD(int, foo, (), (override));
};

class A {

   A(Base* providedBase = new Base)  {
     pointer = providedBase;
    }

    double dosomething()
    {
        //more code
        pointer->foo();
    }

private:
    Base* pointer;
};
```

Now, in your unit test you can provide `BaseMock` in place of `Base`:

```
TEST(A_Test, dosomethingWorksCorrectly)
{
    BaseMock* mock = new BaseMock;
    EXPECT_CALL(*mock, foo()).WillOnce(Return(13));
    A uut(mock);
    uut.dosomething();
}
```

---

Note: avoid using `new` in modern C++. It's a headache to use it correctly and you almost never need it in C++14 and later.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mock `foo` from `Base`, make it `virtual`:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual int foo()
    {

    }
};
```

Define your mock:

```
class MyMock : public Base{
    MOCK_METHOD(int, foo, (), (override));
}
```

You need to add Base as dependency:

```
class A {

   A(Base* ptr):pointer{ptr}  {}

    double dosomething()
    {
        //more code
        pointer->foo();
    }

private:
    Base* pointer;
};
```

Instantiate `MyMock` and use it in your test expectations.